# Java 8 equality of UTC and Zulu time?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, java-8

As far I could research, UTC and Zulu are the same. However I'm running in difficulties comparing two ZonedDateTimes I receive from different sources in my code.
The following code illustrates the problem:

```
@Test
public void equalsOnTimezone() throws Exception {
    ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = ZonedDateTime.of(2015, 2, 1, 14, 30, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    ZonedDateTime zdtZ = ZonedDateTime.of(2015, 2, 1, 14, 30, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("Z"));
    assertEquals(zdtUtc, zdtZ); // will fail
}
```

The problem:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<2015-02-01T14:30Z[UTC]> but was:<2015-02-01T14:30Z>
```

And what will be the correct way to create and compare UTC based values then?

According to W3C [Date and Time Formats](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime):

> Times are expressed in UTC (Coordinated Universal Time), with a special UTC designator ("Z").

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Comparing zone IDs rather than offsets

According to the source code, [`ZonedDateTime::equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) uses [`ZoneId::equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) to compare the zone id component, and that in turn compares the ids rather than the offsets.

If you want two [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) with "different but equivalent" zone ids to compare as equal, you should create them like this, calling [`ZoneId::normalized`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html#normalized()).

```
ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = ZonedDateTime.of(
    2015, 2, 1, 14, 30, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC").normalized());
ZonedDateTime zdtZ = ZonedDateTime.of(
    2015, 2, 1, 14, 30, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("Z").normalized());
```

I think this is a case where your expectations (based on the W3C documentation for the string representations) don't correspond to the documented semantics of the Java classes.  In such cases, the Javadoc is definitive.

(This is *not* a Java 8 bug, IMO.)

Comment: Another option is to convert each ZonedDateTime to an Instant, as the two Instants will be equal.

Comment: Yes ... if that is what you are trying to achieve.